# Variable tracking user attempts does not update

Tags: javascript, html, performance, variables

I am working on a quiz game, and I have been having this issue for a while and I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Ask any question if you are confused by my explanation, i will be monitoring this post

How to recreate the problem - Type in the name displayed on the screen until you see "Game over bro!" - 
Problem:
when I type in the name in the input field and click "Answer" to check if the input field value matches the name retrieved from the API, there is a variable(var attempts = 5) tracking how many times the user has attempted the question,but this variable(attempts) reduces it's value by one when the answer is correct, it should only do that when the answer is incorrect.

Also, let me know what you think about the JS code, is it bad code?
I am asking because the code in newReq function i wrote it twice, one loads and displays the data retrieved from the API when the page loads, the code inside the newReq function loads a new character when "New character" button is clicked.I was thinking about DRY the whole time, but i'm not sure how to load a new character without re-writing the code

```js
var attemptsPara = document.querySelector("#attempts"),
  attempts = 5,
  scorePara = document.querySelector("#score"),
  score = 0,
  feedBackDiv = document.querySelector("#feedBack"),
  newCharacterBtn = document.querySelector("#newCharacter"),
  answerBtn = document.querySelector("#answer"),
  input = document.querySelector("input");

scorePara.textContent = `Score is currently: ${score}`;
attemptsPara.textContent = `${attempts} attempts remaining`;

var feedBackText = document.createElement("p");

var characterPara = document.querySelector("#character");

//click new character button to load new character
// newCharacterBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
//   answerBtn.disabled = false;
//   attempts = 5;
//   attemptsPara.textContent = `${attempts} attempts remaining`;
// });

//function that displays retrieved data to the DOM
function displayCharacters(info) {
  let englishName = info.attributes.name;
  characterPara.textContent = `This is the character's name: ${englishName}`;
  console.log(englishName, randomNumber);
}


//load new character
var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 100 + 2);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open(
  "GET",
  "https://kitsu.io/api/edge/characters/" + randomNumber,
  true
);

request.send();

request.onload = function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  var info = data.data;
  displayCharacters(info);

  //checks if the input value matches name retrieved
  answerBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let englishName = info.attributes.name;
    if (input.value === englishName) {
      feedBackText.textContent = `${input.value} is correct`;
      feedBackDiv.append(feedBackText);
      feedBackDiv.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      feedBackDiv.style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(() => {
        feedBackDiv.style.display = "none";
      }, 3000);
      score = score + 5;
      scorePara.textContent = `Score is currently: ${score}`;
      attempts = 5;
      attemptsPara.textContent = `${attempts} attempts remaining`;
      input.value = "";
      newReq(); //call function to load and display new character
    } else {
      feedBackText.textContent = `${input.value} is wrong`;
      feedBackDiv.append(feedBackText);
      feedBackDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      feedBackDiv.style.display = "block";
      input.focus();
      setTimeout(() => {
        feedBackDiv.style.display = "none";
      }, 2000);
      attempts = attempts - 1;
      attemptsPara.textContent = `${attempts} attempts remaining`;

      if (attempts <= 0) {
        answerBtn.disabled = true;
        attemptsPara.textContent = `Game over bro!`;
      }
    }
    console.log(attempts); //check how many attempts remaining every time answerBtn is clicked
  });
};

newCharacterBtn.addEventListener("click", newReq);

//function to make a new request and display it the information on the DOM,when New character button is clicked
function newReq() {
  rand = randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 100 + 2);
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open(
    "GET",
    "https://kitsu.io/api/edge/characters/" + randomNumber,
    true
  );

  request.send();

  request.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    var info = data.data;
    displayCharacters(info);

    answerBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let englishName = info.attributes.name;
      if (input.value === englishName) {
        feedBackText.textContent = `${input.value} is correct`;
        feedBackDiv.append(feedBackText);
        feedBackDiv.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        feedBackDiv.style.display = "block";
        //settimeout to hide feedBack div
        setTimeout(() => {
          feedBackDiv.style.display = "none";
        }, 3000);
        score = score + 5;
        scorePara.textContent = `Score is currently: ${score}`;
        attempts = 5;
        attemptsPara.textContent = `${attempts} attempts remaining`;
        input.value = "";
        newReq();
      } else if (input.value != englishName) {
        feedBackText.textContent = `${input.value} is wrong`;
        feedBackDiv.append(feedBackText);
        feedBackDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        feedBackDiv.style.display = "block";
        input.focus();
        //settimeout to hide feedBack div
        setTimeout(() => {
          feedBackDiv.style.display = "none";
        }, 2000);
        attempts = attempts - 1;
        attemptsPara.textContent = `${attempts} attempts remaining`;

        if (attempts <= 0) {
          answerBtn.disabled = true;
          attemptsPara.textContent = `Game over bro!`;
        }
      }
    });
    console.log(attempts);
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
}

#imageHolder {
  height: 560px;
  width: 1100px;
  background: #098;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

#buttonHolder {
  /* background: #453; */
  width: 160px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p,
h3 {
  color: yellowgreen;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

button,
input {
  margin: 10px 10px;
  border: none;
  background: #098;
  display: block;
}

input {
  background: white;
}


/* for the question and awnswer game */

#feedBack {
  background: #098;
  height: 120px;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="score"></p>

<p id="character"></p>

<input type="text"> <button id="answer">Answer</button> <button id="newCharacter">New Character</button>

<p id="attempts"></p>

<div id="feedBack">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises from calling `answerBtn.addEventListener` every time the answer returns - which adds more and more listeners.

Add a console log at the beginning of the `click` event and you'll see that after the 2nd answer the click event happens twice, then three times on the 3rd answer, etc'. 
This means that on the first click the result is correct, but then on the rest of the clicks it is incorrect and must be causing the bug.

You should only listen to the event once, the variables that the event uses change and that should be sufficient. I can't fix the code for you at this time, apologies.